# loop thorough a json object and pull data - js

Tags: javascript, json, api, loops, object

I want to take data from an API that had a ton of drinks and their info. 
I'm a noob. I managed to access the info (as shown in the code sample) but I cant seem to think of a correct way to loop though it and collect the relevant data in good order (new object for each drink).

The file has an object called "drinks". which had more objects that go from "0" to "4". From each one I want the name, id, category.

API returns :

```
drinks  
0:  {…}
1:  {…}
2:  {…}
3:  {…}
4:  {…}
```

each number is an object with a lot of info i.e name, id, category ect.

I get when console.log(drinkX) :

```
Object { drink: "Margarita", id: "13060", category: "Ordinary Drink" }
Object { drink: "Blue Margarita", id: "11118", category: "Ordinary Drink" }
Object { drink: "Tommy's Margarita", id: "17216", category: "Ordinary Drink" }
Object { drink: "Whitecap Margarita", id: "16158", category: "Other/Unknown" }
Object { drink: "Strawberry Margarita", id: "12322", category: "Ordinary Drink" }
```

But I cant seem to access only one object because console.log(drinkX) returns them all. Neither can I access only one name for example.

This is what I've done. How can I create a new object for each drink so I can easily access each individual drink/name/category ?

```
      let url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita';
  fetch(url)
  .then((res) => { return res.json() })
  .then((data) => {
      let result = `<h2> Drink Info From API</h2>`;
      for( i=0; i <= 4; i++){
        let drinkX = {
          drink: data.drinks[i].strDrink,
          id: data.drinks[i].idDrink,
          category: data.drinks[i].strCategory

        };
          console.log(drinkX);
      }
          })
```

Comment: Could you print the response from the API and your expected results?

Comment: ofc. I edited the question and added examples. @SamuelVaillant

Answer (score 1):

Not `=<`. Should be `<=` Also, not `data.for(..)` Only `for(..)`

```js
 let url = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita';
      fetch(url)
      .then((res) => { return res.json() })
      .then((data) => {
          let result = `<h2> Drink Information </h2>`;
          for(let i=0; i <= data.drinks.length; i++){
            let drinkName = data.drinks[i].strDrink;
          console.log(drinkName)
          }
    });
```

Comment: thanks man, I changed the code a bit and made the question more specific regarding managing the info I get from the API.

Answer (score 1):

As API returns JSON object (Array of objects). You can use for ... of loop to iterate each object and access the information.

```js
var jsonObj = [{
  "drink": "Margarita",
  "id": "13060",
  "category": "Ordinary Drink"
 },
 {
  "drink": "Blue Margarita",
  "id": "11118",
  "category": "Ordinary Drink"
 },
 {
  "drink": "Tommy's Margarita",
  "id": "17216",
  "category": "Ordinary Drink"
 },
 {
  "drink": "Whitecap Margarita",
  "id": "16158",
  "category": "Other/Unknown"
 },
 {
  "drink": "Strawberry Margarita",
  "id": "12322",
  "category": "Ordinary Drink"
 }];
  
for (var obj of jsonObj) {
  console.log(obj.drink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Object Oriented Programming.

The objects are being created in the forEach loop. I also added a 'findBeverageById' method to illustrate how you could search the array of Beverages and use it somewhere.

```js
class Beverage{
  constructor( id, name, category ){
    this.id = parseInt( id );
    this.name = name;
    // category probably doesn't really belong in the beverage class,
    // but I put it here for this answer
    this.category = category; 
  }
  
  getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  
  getCategory(){
    return this.category;
  }
}

// manages an array of beverages
class BeverageManager{
  constructor(){
    this.beverages = [];
  }
  
  addBeverage( beverage ){
    this.beverages.push( beverage );
  }
  
  findBeverageById( index){
      return this.beverages.find( beverage => beverage.id === index );
  }
}

const drinks = [
  { drink: "Margarita", id: "13060", category: "Ordinary Drink" },
  { drink: "Blue Margarita", id: "11118", category: "Ordinary Drink" },
  { drink: "Tommy's Margarita", id: "17216", category: "Ordinary Drink" },
  { drink: "Whitecap Margarita", id: "16158", category: "Other/Unknown" },
  { drink: "Strawberry Margarita", id: "12322", category: "Ordinary Drink" }
];

let beverageManager = new BeverageManager();
// create beverages and store them in objects
drinks.forEach( drink => {
  let beverage = new Beverage( drink.id, drink.drink, drink.category);
  beverageManager.addBeverage( beverage );
});


// Try it out on 2 drinks
let foundBeverage = beverageManager.findBeverageById( 11118 );
console.log( `Found a(n) ${foundBeverage.getCategory()} called ${foundBeverage.getName()}` );

foundBeverage = beverageManager.findBeverageById( 16158 );
console.log( `Found a(n) ${foundBeverage.getCategory()} called ${foundBeverage.getName()}` );
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you !
Thought somewhat understand what you did here, I need to learn more about "constructor" and "this".
Also, my main struggle right now is how do I achieve "const drinks" (in your example) from that API.

Comment: `const drinks` is meant to mimic the json-response you get from your http request. ( `const` is quite similar in functionality to `var` and `let`) If you want to learn more about OOP read the MDN documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects. After that you might want to consider looking into Design Patterns.